# Scripts on page - the page doesnt open on a first attempt

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox

I need help. I am just a beginner in writing web pages, so I hope my question isnt silly. The problem is, that my page doesnt load on a first attempt on a mobile device. (On desktop PC it works normally). I will give you a little background, what steps I made before this problem happened.

1. I have created websites with lightbox script loading at the start of the page. (I have adjusted the script to work in lower resolutions on mobile phones first) It made it work not properly, when it was opened on a mobile device. The windows were not fitting well on the screen etc..
2. I have solved this by putting the script at the end of html body. The lightbox works well now, but the page with the gallery doesnt open on a first attempt. I have to refresh the page and then the page appears normally and works without problems.
3. I have been searching for possible solution to this problem through the whole web, but with no success.

   - I am attaching my code (I have avoided some metatags, paragraphs with text, navigating toolbar etc. to shorten it and make it easier for you to read it and decode the problem.

I will be glad for any help I can get. :) Thanks a lot. Please, let me know on my e-mail, when answered or a problem with my question.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>...</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.merryberry.eu/galerie.html">
    <link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="stylesheetmobil.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Body">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="menu">
          <nav id="primary_nav_wrap"> </nav>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="picture">
        <img src="Images/barvenidekorace.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
      </div>
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You mentioned that it worked fine at full desktop size, and was only any issue on mobile. If you scale the browser window on the desktop so that it is similar in size to a mobile screen prior to loading the page, does the problem occur?

Comment: Hi Brice, on PC works it perfectly, even if I adjust the window size to be similar to mobile device resolution. I am using even the same browsers for mobile and for desktop PC.